# Ubuntu Battery/AC Management

Tags: 12.10, power-management

I would like to know if having the AC plugged continues to charge the battery while being 100%.

I don't want my battery to wear out, and I don't want to have to remove it every time I plug the AC in. Is this possible in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has been well answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power).

**The gist of the answer:** While keeping your laptop continuously on AC power or charging and discharging it frequently doesn't matter, what matters is its temperature; if it gets heated often, you are reducing your battery's life.